# Calling functions from section 2 of the manual in C++

Tags: c++, linux, system-calls

Section 2 of the Unix manual covers system calls (though they might actually be implemented by the system libc - `fork(2)` on Linux for example). The following is a very dumb example that calls `open(2)` and `close(2)`.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int fd;

  fd = open("/dev/null", O_APPEND);
  close(fd);
}
```

It's been a while since I've written a lot of C++ code. I'm curious if C++ libraries now have a more C++ way to access these functions w/o having to include a lot of C header files? The code above is straight C essentially.

The lower level functions are still useful if you want to move file descriptors around (make sure fd's 0, 1 and 2 are what you want them to be) or do ioctls, etc. But enums and some better typing might be nice for the args.

Comment: What do you mean by the C++ way?  When there are so MANY wasys to choose from.  Perhaps you mean << and >> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm curious if C++ libraries now have a more C++ way to access these functions w/o having to include a lot of C header files?

They don't, since those functions are provided by POSIX and not a feature of the language.  What is provided, however, are `iostream` abstractions (C++98, chapter 27) which do much of the common functionality of the "section 2" `open()`/`close()`/`read()`/`write()` calls.

C++11 provides yet more abstractions which cover more of the functionality provided by the POSIX, Windows (etc) APIs.

Comment: As documented [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/)? Perhaps [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/) as well?

Comment: Yes, those are the ones.